# Local Database MDF Connection error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to connect to a local `.mdf` database file with C# to make use of the string below, the strange thing is that I get this exception.

I state that I am an administrator on the machine where I am developing the software, in the `model` folder there is only one file called `local.mdf`, how can I solve it and what is due? Thank you

**Exception:**

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file: C:......\bin\Debug\Model\local.mdf  A database with same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Connection string:

```
Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;
AttachDbFilename =|DataDirectory|\\bin\\Debug\\Model\\local.mdf; 
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Comment: What kind of application is this one? What is the value of |DataDirectory| ?

Comment: try to remove |DataDirectory| and write the full path of the dataBase

Comment: @kaj with full path i have same error

Comment: @Steve it's a desktop application

Comment: would u try to replace AttachDBFilename with Initial Catalog with the full path

Comment: In a Desktop Application the |DataDirectory| substitution string already resolves to the BIN\DEBUG folder (when you run your app inside a Visual Studio session) thus your connection string should resolve to _.\bin\debug\bin\debug\model\local.mdf_ I would try two steps. First remove the bin\debug constant from your connectionstring. Second add a logical name for your instance through the _Initial Catalog=MyData;_ (or something you prefer for the instance name). In this way it should be clear that you are trying to reach the instance and only if the instance is missing then attach the file name.